# How do I extract just the Postal Code from Google Geocoding

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to build a mobile website, and this site uses Google geolocation services to determine you location and returns a list of stores in a 30 mile radius. this works great, I use the lat and lon to then find the formal address, but in the code=behind I am trying to extract just the postal code, the problem is it keeps changing. here is the code, any help would be appreciated.

```
 // Find the user's, Latitude and Longitude, then using Reverse Geolocation ... get the User Location
    function showPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        // This is making the Geocode request
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               // alert(status);
            }
            // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
                document.getElementById('userlocation').value = address;
                document.getElementById('services').value = "on";
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What is it that keeps changing?

Comment: well... I was using results[2] ... and here at work it would say "Chicago, IL 60601, USA", at home it would add my neighborhood "Lakeview, Chicago IL, USA" ... so I changed it to results[0] and now it seems to be working, the real test will be when I get home tonight. but, I thought that maybe I could detect or isolate just the Postal Code.

Comment: I think you can get just the postcode by doing this: `results[0]['address_components'][0].long_name` e.g. SW1A 1AA (UK).